# How to fill window in UIKit for macOS application

Tags: ios, macos, autolayout, uikit

I recently discovered that it is possible to build an iOS application for macOS simply by ticking a check box in the build settings. However, when the application launches, it does not fill the entire window:

[image]

How can I enable this behavior? The application uses auto layout, so it should theoretically be able to dynamically respond to changes in window size.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. I had the following legacy code in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`:

```swift
window?.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
```

Removing this code resolved the issue, and did not break my iOS versions.